# How can i set input field on Magento 2 admin data grid in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, frontend, product-grid

i create magento product data grid on front and creat one add to cart button for selected product add to cart .
but in that i need to set quantity field as input field user can fill quantity as per they need

[image]

how can i set input field as here.

> my ui component xml file is here
> /Module/Vendor/view/frontend/ui_component/wk_product_list_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">wk_product_list_custom.wk_product_list_custom_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">wk_product_list_custom.wk_product_list_custom_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">products_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="wk_product_list_custom_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Webkul\CustomModule\Ui\DataProvider\ProductList</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">wk_product_list_custom_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="custommodule/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="products_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">wk_productGrid</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">wk_selectProduct</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product SKU</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255014/12110977

Comment: okay let me try this one

Comment: @JayParmar did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hello @RahulBarot I don't think your answer in comment is relevant to the question asked here. The question asked here is to add a input field in the admin grid. But you have shared the answer for adding a link in admin grid. Both cases are very much different. If you can share any answers regarding adding the input field in the admin grid, it will be very much useful. Thanks

Comment: yes this shared answer for link , but main things are in that link file i add input field than my work done , conclusion is we can add html widget in admin grid column .

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: config the column like this:

```
<column name="custom_field2" class="MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\HTMLLink">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <!-- other configurations -->
           <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Step 2: create file

> <Magento_ROOT>/app/code/MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/HtmlLink.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;

class HTMLLink extends Column{
    protected $escaper;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Escaper $escaper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource){
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $html = '<input type="text" name="field_name" >';
                $item[$fieldName] = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($html, ['a']);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

}